# React does not render selected attribute

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm using some SSR technique to prerender my React powered app. There is a `select` implemented on my page, that has one of it's options preselected depending on some environment values.

However, the state of React is correct, but when I **hydrate** the static HTML with ReactDOM the first option is always selected visually. It seems to be a problem with the missing `selected` attribute. This visual flaw gets corrected when some of the state gets updated.

I'm using this snippet, which is working fine (but it misses the rendered `selected`).

```
return (
  <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.handleChange}>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>
);
```

Is there a way to enforce the rendering of `selected` or to rerender manually after the hydration?

Comment: Are you initializing your SSR script with the env variables ?

Comment: Yeah, I already checked if the SSR code execution is correct. And it is. The state is fine, everything is working, except that I can't see the correct selection in the resulting HTML.

Comment: It it pure intention that React doesn't render `selected` attributes. For the same reasons they don't render `value` attributes (anymore). However, it would be awesome if there is some kind of sane workaround.